# Get client-ID through Message in JMS

Tags: java, jms, messaging

i'm trying to get the client-id (or connection-id) of a message consumer through a message in JMS.

Is there a way to get it, when i'm only have access to a received message (like in the `onMessage` method of the `MessageListener` interface)?

Short: i have a jms message and i want to know the client-id of the consumer who received the message

Answer (score 1):

A Connection object is a client's active connection to its JMS provider. It typically 
allocates provider resources outside the Java virtual machine (JVM).
Method of Connection Interface provides following method.

```
String getClientID() throws JMSException
```

This value is specific to the JMS provider. It is either preconfigured by an administrator in a ConnectionFactory object or assigned dynamically by the application by calling the setClientID method.

Comment: Ok, so i need the instance of the `Connection`class and i don't have a chance to get the client-id only through a instance of the `Message`class?

Comment: yes you have to take the instance of the connection class for getting the client-id.there is no scope to get the client-id through Message class instance.